# При повторном переборе массива всегда возвращается последнее значение

Tags: c++

Вроде простейшая задача, но какая-то фигня.
Сам код:

```cpp
    label1->Text = "";
    label4->Text = "";
    using namespace std;

    int** circles = new int*[5];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int X = 50 + rand() % 600;
        int Y = 50 + rand() % 500;
        int coord[2] = { X, Y };
        circles[i] = coord;

        label1->Text += i.ToString() + ": " + circles[i][0].ToString() + ":" + circles[i][1].ToString() + "\n";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        label4->Text += i.ToString() + ": " + circles[i][0].ToString() + ":" + circles[i][1].ToString() + "\n";
    }
```

Повторный перебор массива возвращает в label4 только последнее значение. Как с этим быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив `coord` - локальный массив в теле цикла. Он уничтожается в конце каждой итерации цикла.

То есть в итоге у вас все указатели в массиве `circles` указывают на уже уничтоженные массивы. Дальнейшее поведение пне определено. Зачем вы сохраняете указатели на массивы, которые тут же будут уничтожены?

Ваше "только последнее значение" - это не более чем случайное проявление неопределенного поведения.